# Is the word celestial used in scientific context?

Tags: word-usage, antonyms

I think the word terrestrial is common prominent term for biology-related contexts but when we look at the word celestial, it is not antonym of the word terrestrial because of the religious meaning given to it.

I would like to ask if the word celestial is used in scientific context and if is not what could possible antonym of the word terrestrail be in terms of science.

Comment: "Celestial" is definitely used in scientific contexts. It is used to refer to stars, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In a scientific context, you are more likely to find [**extraterrestrial**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/extraterrestrial):

> *adjective*
>
> 1) existing, taking place, or coming from outside the limits of the earth